Asymptotic Inequality
Let $(u_n)_{n \geq 2}$  the sequence defined by :
$$
u_n = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{(n-1)(2n-1)} \quad \text{for all} \quad n \geq 2. $$
I wonder if Is there an elegant way to prove the following inequality
$$
u_n^q - u_n^{-q} \geq  \frac{6q}{n}
$$
for some real $ q \in \left(0, \infty \right) $ and all integers $ n \geq 2.$
I tried first to take $x= \frac{1}{n}$ and write inequality only depending on $x$, but it seems that inequality becomes more harder. the LHS is exactly the first order of the series expansion of  RHS, the question actualy is there any possibility to show such inequality without a brute forcing methode using $x ?$

You could start with the partial fraction decomposition $$u_n=1+\frac6{n-1}-\frac6{2n-1}$$ and use inequalities for $\left(1+O(\frac1n)\right)^{\pm q}$.

I tried before, and got the inequality only for $n$ larger enough.

@Reyansh Did any of us answer your question?

We aim to prove the inequality
$$
\sinh (q \log u_n) \ge \frac{3q}{n}
$$
for $n \geq 2$ and $q \geq 0$.
Observe that
$$
q\log u_n  = 2q\tanh ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) + 2q\tanh ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{1}{{2n}}} \right) \ge 2q\frac{1}{n} + 2q\frac{1}{{2n}} = \frac{{3q}}{n},
$$
for $n \geq 2$ and $q \geq 0$.
Hence,
$$
\sinh (q \log u_n) \geq q \log u_n \geq \frac{3q}{n}
$$
for $n \geq 2$ and $q \geq 0$.

[+1] Very nice proof!

Using $u_n > 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$u_n^q \ge \frac{3q + \sqrt{n^2 + 9q^2}}{n}. \tag{1}$$
We can prove that $u_n \ge \mathrm{e}^{3/n}$ for all $n\ge 2$ (easy by taking derivative). Thus, to prove (1), it suffices to prove that
$$\mathrm{e}^{3q/n} \ge \frac{3q + \sqrt{n^2 + 9q^2}}{n},$$
or (using $\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u + \frac12 u^2$ for all $u\ge 0$)
$$1 + 3q/n + \frac12 (3q/n)^2 \ge \frac{3q + \sqrt{n^2 + 9q^2}}{n}$$
which is true.
We are done.

Let $f_n(q) = u_n^q - u_n^{-q} - \frac{6q}n$. Clearly, $f_n(0)=0$. Now, we have
$$
f_n’(q) = \ln u_n (u_n^q + u_n^{-q}) -\frac6n.
$$
In particular, $f_n’(0) = 2\ln u_n -\frac6n \ge 0$ because
\begin{align}
\ln u_n &= \ln(1+1/n) -\ln(1-1/n) + \ln(1+1/2n) -\ln(1-1/2n)
\\
&= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1) n^{2k+1}} + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1) (2n)^{2k+1}}
\\
&\ge \frac3n.
\end{align}
Furthermore, for all $q\ge 0$, we have
$$
f_n’’(q) = (\ln u_n)^2 (u_n^q - u_n^{-q}) \ge 0,
$$
because $u_n >1$ for all $n\ge 2$. Therefore, $f_n’(q) \ge 0$ and hence $f_n(q)\ge 0$ for all $q\ge 0$.

A better inequality :
Write
$$u_n = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{(n-1)(2n-1)}$$
$$u_n^{-1} = \frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{(n+1)(2n+1)}$$
So
$$u_n^q - u_n^{-q} =(\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{(n-1)(2n-1)})^q - (\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{(n+1)(2n+1)})^q $$
Giving
$$u_n^q - u_n^{-q} = \left(\frac{1+3/2n +1/n^2}{1-3/2n+1/n^2}\right)^q - \left(\frac{1-3/2n +1/n^2}{1+3/2n+1/n^2}\right)^q$$
Now with $n\geq 2$:
$$ 1 -3/2n +1/n^2 \leq 1 $$
$$ 1+3/2n+1/n^2 \geq 1$$
Giving inequality :
$$ u_n^q - u_n^{-q} \geq \left(\frac{1+3/2n +1/n^2}{1}\right)^q - \left(\frac{1-3/2n +1/n^2}{1}\right)^q$$
Using generalized binomial :
$$ (1+3/2n + 1/n^2)^q=\sum_{i=0}^\infty {q \choose i}(3/2n+1/n^2)^i $$
$$ (1-3/2n + 1/n^2)^q=\sum_{i=0}^\infty {q \choose i}(-3/2n+1/n^2)^i $$
So
$$ u_n^q - u_n^{-q} \geq \sum_{i=1}^\infty {q \choose i}\left((3/2n+1/n^2)^i-(-3/2n+1/n^2)^i\right) $$
Using again Newton :
$$ u_n^q - u_n^{-q} \geq \sum_{i=0}^\infty {q \choose i}\left((3/2n+1/n^2)^i-(-3/2n+1/n^2)^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty {q \choose i}\left(\sum_{k=0}^i{i \choose k}(1-(-1)^k)(3/2n)^k(1/n^2)^{i-k}   \right)  $$
Simply.
$$ u_n^q - u_n^{-q} \geq  \sum_{i=1}^\infty {q \choose i}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor i-1 \rfloor /2}2{i \choose 2k+1}(3/2n)^k(1/n^2)^{i-k}   \right) \geq \dfrac{6q}{n}  $$

Yes well seen, have you any idea to improve ?
